# Is there an easy way to recreate string with variables concatenated by `+` to python f-string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, f-string

I am currently refactoring poorly written legacy code, with code snippets like this:

```
sql_tmp = (
                func_out
                + "(case when "
                + self.time_name
                + ">="
                + str(int(aggFrom))
                + " and "
                + segm_var
                + " = '"
                + segment
                + "'"
                + " then "
                + colName
                + " end)"
            )
```

or

```
 print(
 "Variable",
 newColName,
 "fill share <",
 str(self.min_fill_share),
 "(",
 self.nr_columns_done_print,
 "/",
 self.nr_columns_total,
 ")",
 )
```

I would like to have an easy way to reformat these strings into Python f-string.

AFAIK PyCharm has a way to redo `"".format()` type of strings into f-strings, but it does not work with pluses.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you specifically asking if VS Code can do it or if PyCharm can do it? Or are you asking in general if there's a tool make the change?

Comment: And FYI the latter case isn't any better or worse than an f-string if you're doing this performance like the string concatenation.

Comment: ad 1) any tool. in the end i wrote my own script.

Comment: ad 2) i don't care about performance. i care about readability, and this is unreadable

Answer (score 0):

I decided to write my own script, and I paste the code snippet into long string.

```
"".join([
    # creating f-string variable, if the string has no " on side of it
    "{" + stripped + "}"

    if '"' not in stripped[0]

    # removing "
    else stripped.replace('"', "")
    for stripped in [
        # removing whitespace and dividing the string by '+'
        x.strip() for x in " ".join(code_snippet.split()).split("+") 
    ]
])
```

Comment: How would you use this code? And are you sure this is the actual working code? Because it does not seem valid Python code (at least the formatting does not make sense).